# how to send email notification to developer for build failure in Jenkins

Tags: email, selenium, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration

I have a continuous integration setup and integrated selenium scripts in jenkins. In case of failure in build, mail notifications should be sent to the developer who commited the changes. I run selenium scripts in jenkins to verify the status of the build. The problem is that if there is any failure, email notifications are sent to the selenium script developer instead of the application developer. It assumes that build is getting failed due to the changes made in selenium script but the actual issue is with the application code.

Is there any way to send mail to application developers for build failure instead of selenium script developer ?

Answer (score 2):

I would have preferred to write this response as comment rather than answer, but due to insufficient rep, am posting it anyways.
If you want to send email notifications to particular email address, check out **Email-ext plugin**. With this you can add post build action of Editable Email Notifications and control which email address you send notifications and when(if your job fails or success)

[image]

Comment: i already have this setup. In addition to the recipient list, i also want to send mail to the developer automatically who is reason for the build failure.

Comment: it is always sending mail to the selenium script developer instead of application developer

Comment: well I am not sure how to configure jenkins to send mail specifically to those developers who caused its failure, but as a closing note, I would like to point out "Include Culprits" checkbox. It isnt exactly what you are looking, but somewhat close to it I guess. "Include Culprits - If this is checked AND Send To Developers is checked, emails will include everyone who committed since the last successful build."

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use email-ext plugin as mentioned above. Secondly, ensure you select 'upstream committers' option. As per its own description: "Sends email to the list of users who committed changes in upstream builds that triggered this build." If your application build triggers a selenium build, this is what you need.